# Fundamental group of the complement of $3$ disjoint hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{C}P^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-space, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be the union of $3$ hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{C}P^2$, then how to compute the $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}P^2\setminus X)$?

What I know is the complement of a hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ is $\mathbb{C}^2$. I can't go further.

Comment: It seems that your "hypersurface" complex projective line. If so, put one of these lines at infinity, and make two other lines coordinate axes. Then think about fibering the rest over some Riemann surface.

Comment: @Moishe can you explain more. Your words always confused me.

Comment: what do you mean by disjoint in this case ?

Comment: It depends on the hypersurface!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the lines of @MoisheKohan after a change of co-ordinates you can assume one of your hypersurfaces is $H_3=\{[z_1:z_2:z_3]\in \mathbb C\mathbb P^2  | \ z_3= 0 \}$

$ \mathbb C \mathbb P^2-H_3\cong\mathbb C^2$

Thus you are reduced to computing $\pi_1(\mathbb C^2-l_1\cup l_2)$ where $l_1, \ l_2$ are two complex straight lines. Again after a change of co-ordinates you can assume $l_1=\{(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb C^2 :z_1=0\}$ and $l_2=\{(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb C^2 :z_2=0\}$

Then you have $\mathbb C^2 -l_1\cup l_2=\mathbb C^*\times \mathbb C^*$

So you get $$\pi_1(\mathbb C^2-l_1\cup l_2)=\pi_1(\mathbb C^*)\times \pi_1(\mathbb C^*)=\mathbb Z^2$$

Thus $$\pi_1(\mathbb C\mathbb P^2-H_1\cup H_2 \cup H_3)=\mathbb Z^2$$

Comment: But your $l_1\cap l_2=(0,0)$ while i require $l_1\cap l_2\cap l_3=\emptyset$

Comment: This is in $\mathbb C^2$ not in $ \mathbb C \mathbb P^2$

Comment: The homeomorphism from $CP^2-H_3$ to $C^2$ makes them intersect?

Comment: If not they will be parallel and since both of them pass through $(0,0)$ they are the same line. They pass through the origin since they are subspaces after all .